# Does the Travis V3 API return builds older than two years?

Tags: travis-ci

I've been using the Travis V3 API to scrape builds for some repos. Using the following url:

```
https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/AnalyticalGraphicsInc%2Fcesium/builds?sort_by=finished_at
```

However, no matter what project I use, the oldest build being returned is always somewhere around 2016-07-20. While there are older builds that can be found through GitHub pull requests for this project. For instance [this](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/2281) pull request which has builds from 2014. I couldn't find anything in the docs stating that there is a cut-off date before which no builds are returned. So I'm wondering if there is anything can do about this.